# How to calculate the difference between elements x[i+1] and x[i-1]?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array `A`, with size `n`, I want a function that returns an array `R` with size `n-2` such that `R[i] = A[i+1] - A[i-1]`.

I tried to check the options of `numpy.diff` but apparently it only calculates the difference between consecutive elements, i.e., `A[i+1] - A[i]`.

Comment: Isn't this just one loop?

Answer (score 6):

You can directly subtract the slices of the first n-2 values from the last n-2 values, or vice versa:

```py
>>> r = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> r[2:], r[:-2]
(array([3, 4, 5, 6]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
>>> r[:-2] - r[2:]   # r[i] = r[i-1] - r[i+1]
array([-2, -2, -2, -2])
>>> r[2:] - r[:-2]   # r[i] = r[i+1] - r[i-1]
array([2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Both slicing and element-wise subtraction are performed by `numpy` and thus have minimal overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a small function that does this:

```py
def diff(A):
    R = []
    for i in range(1,len(A)-1):
        R.append(A[i+1]-A[i-1])
    return R
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```py
R = [A[i+1] - A[i-1] for i in range(1,len(A)-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
numpy.diff(r[1:])+numpy.diff(r[:-1])
```